# A Record Configuration: Host Content on Webserver IP and Smtp IP From Another Server

Tags: email, webserver, smtp, webmin, hosting-services

I’m stuck on a basic dns issue here "I think". I can send email but unable to receive.

What I want to achieve is host webfiles of my webpage on 184.69.151.38 and use smtp ip from
193.47.34.77.

I think my A records might be wrong.
[image]

What is happening is mxtoolbox is picking up as the email server as 184.69.151.38 but the smtp is supposed to be sending from 193.47.34.77.  *Likely* dns issue.  I'm just not seeing it.

[image]

Yet smtp test looks *decent*, not perfect but should work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tell mxtoolbox to "Test Email Server" named `jessemacdougall.com`, it does exactly what you told it to do. You're not testing "the mail server of domain jessemacdougall.com" - you are testing whether server `jessemacdougall.com` can successfully receive mail. And if you use the "DNS Lookup" function, the only actually published A record for that name is 184.69.151.38.

I'm guessing that the A record with a Name of just `.` and a Value of `193.47.34.77` is being rejected by the DNS server as being outside the DNS zone. You probably should delete that record altogether.

(In DNS records, a name that ends in `.` is supposed to be fully qualified. A name that is *only* `.` effectively claims to be one of the root DNS servers of the whole Internet - and you definitely don't want to claim *that* by accident, hence the sanity check.)

If you want to test the mail reception capabilities of 193.47.34.77, you should use either the IP address or the name `magnifies.jessemacdougall.com`. This allows the mxtoolbox to be used to test servers *before* they are placed into full production use (by pointing the domain's MX records at the server).

You are receiving email because there is a MX record telling the world that the name of the server that handles the mail of domain `jessemacdougall.com` is actually `magnifies.jessemacdougall.com`:

```
jessemacdougall.com.    3600    IN      MX      10 magnifies.jessemacdougall.com.
```

Because of this record, mail servers on the internet will know to connect to `magnifies.jessemacdougall.com` i.e. IP address 193.47.34.77 if they have mail to deliver for you.

*The receiving mail server of domain `jessemacdougall.com` does not have to be named `jessemacdougall.com`.* It might even be in another domain altogether, as long as the MX record is correctly set and the server administrator has configured the server to accept mail addressed to the `jessemacdougall.com` domain.

There is one special case where the mail server name would need to match the domain name. That is when the domain has no MX records at all. But this is poor practice: a valid receiving mail server should have MX record(s) pointing to it. This leaves the A record corresponding to the domain name free for other purposes: in most cases (like yours) it is used for a web server.

In order to clear the "SMTP Banner Check", the email software on 193.47.34.77 would need to state its name as `magnifies.jessemacdougall.com` in the SMTP Banner. In most cases, this means configuring that name as the canonical hostname in the SMTP software on that host.

Your problems with outgoing email might be caused by your SPF record. When looking up published DNS records of type TXT for your domain, I can currently see:

```
jessemacdougall.com.    1021    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 -all"
jessemacdougall.com.    1021    IN      TXT     "google-site-verification=U3GFANwgQpWi8WIXsp-zvrb9sqxO5FxW14f5qquz0IU"
```

The first line is the SPF record. The `v=spf1 -all` means that any outgoing mail servers not listed in the SPF record should explicitly be considered invalid - but then the record lists no *valid* outgoing mail servers at all. So effectively, your domain's SPF record is currently saying "this domain will not send any legitimate mail at all: if you see any email claiming to originate from here, it is the result of forgery/malware and should be summarily discarded as spam." No wonder you cannot successfully send anything!

If you want to send outgoing mail to the internet from 193.47.34.77, the value of the SPF record should instead be:

```
v=spf1 ip4:193.47.34.77 -all
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Much appreciated your not wasting your pearls here friend. 
I made a mistake though; I can send mail but not receive it using qmail. 
The period. you outline is actually a wildcard/* does your answer change?
My proprietary software auto generates the dns so I believe the spf record is fine, however I did try what you suggested with no luck.  The spf is currently the way you suggested.  Could it take 24-48 hours to propagate?  This smells like a software problem i may have to contact the engineer.

Comment: Your current SPF record seems to have a typo: it currently has value `v=spf1 ip:4 193.47.34.77 -all`. It should be `... ip4:<valid sender IP> ...` with no space between the `ip4:` prefix and the IP address.

Comment: thanks EagleEye, I changed it same effect.